# Bitcoin-cli access - how do I access it?

Tags: blockchain

newbie question here. I am trying to learn to interact with the Bitcoin blockchain and I want to use the native SCRIPT language.

I already downloaded the entire node and synced on an AWS Linux Ubuntu but I did it using Bitcore.io.  I can see it's using Node.js and I can see no option of using the bitcoin CLI. The best tutorials out there are in for Bitcoin's native language.

Do I have to re-download the entire chain from bitcoin.org in order to the native command line?

I want to use all the features, not just a 'light' option like BitcoinJ.

Any suggestion appreciated.

Comment: `bitcoin-cli` is a completely separate binary that you may need to install. Also, you cannot just "use the native script language" with bitcoin-cli; the scripting language is for transactions.

Comment: of course you can. There is even a resource for woking with scripts.https://github.com/ChristopherA/Learning-Bitcoin-from-the-Command-Line

My question was what do I do now after I installed the node with bitcore instead of using the bitcoin.org. Is it possible to link the bitcoin-cli with my node?

Comment: That tutorial doesn't use bitcoin-cli for anything with scripts except examining them. To do anything else, you have to use other software. Anyways, to use bitcoin-cli you have to have bitcoind (aka Bitcoin Core) installed. bitcoin-cli only works with bitcoind.

Comment: Thanks a lot Andrew, I understand now. I made a confusion between the bitcoin-cli and using other software.